# Removing Space between variable and string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, printing

My code looks like this:

```
name = Joe
print "Hello", name, "!"
```

My output looks like:

```
Hello Joe !
```

How do I remove the space between `Joe` and `!`?

Comment: Please use the checkmark next to an answer to accept it and let others know that it was the solution to your problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways of constructing strings in python. My favorite used to be the format function:

```py
print "Hello {}!".format(name)
```

You can also concatenate strings using the + operator.

```py
print "Hello " + name + "!"
```

More information about the format function (and strings in general) can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format

### 6 Years Later...

You can now use something called [`f-Strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) if you're using python 3.6 or newer. Just prefix the string with the letter `f` then insert variable names inside some brackets.

```py
print(f"Hello {name}")
```

Answer (score 2):

a comma after print will add a blank space.

What you need to do is concatenate the string you want to print; this can be done like this:

```
name = 'Joe'
print 'Hello ' +  name + '!'
```

`Joe` must be put between `quotes` to define it as a string.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print (name)
Joe
>>> print('Hello ', name, '!')
Hello  Joe !
>>> print('Hello ', name, '!', sep='')
Hello Joe!
```

Comment: This solution will work for Python 3 only. I want to point this out since this question is tagged with python-2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `printf` style formatting:

```
>>> name = 'Joe'
>>> print 'Hello %s !' % name
Hello Joe !
```

Answer (score 1):

One other solution would be to use the following:

```
Print 'Hello {} !'.format(name.trim())
```

This removes all the leading and trailing spaces and special character.